# Number of digits of N factorial in base B

Tags: logarithms, factorial

Given the decimal integers **N** and **B**. How can the number of digits in **N!** in base **B** be calculated without calculating the value of **N!**?

Example: If **N** **= 5** and **B** **=** **2**, then **N! = 5! = 120**.
Representing the value in base **B**, we get **1111000** which has **7** digits.

But I'm trying to get the result without calculating the value of **N!**.

Comment: Hint: $\lceil\log_bN!\rceil$.

Comment: Would you please explain?

Comment: A base-$b$ number of $d$ digits lies between $b^{d-1}$ and $b^d-1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of digits is $\lfloor\log_b N!\rfloor+1$. This can be rewritten as $$\Big\lfloor\sum_{r=1}^N\log_br\Big\rfloor+1.$$
That sum should be possible to calculate on computer even for relatively large $N$. However, you can also approximate it using Stirling's formula:$$\ln N!\approx(N+1/2)\ln N-N+\ln\sqrt{2\pi}.$$
To convert this to what you want, use the fact that $\log_bx=\frac{\ln x}{\ln b}$.

This approximation is pretty good. For $\log_25!$ it gives $6.883$, whereas the actual value is $6.907$.